Temporary table already exists on SqlServer
Why this behavior with SqlServer
IF @xx = 1
  SELECT x.col1 INTO #tbl FROM x
ELSE
  SELECT y.col1 INTO #tbl FROM y

error when running : Table #tbl already exists

When the statement is compiled, the parser doesn't do IFs, it just follows along linewise and sees same table being created twice. But your code is wrong any way, because you cannot create a table with a nameless column which 1 and 2 are

Yes right, but just for this purpose, I fix the command
